# Extract Json Column Data in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a JSON column that has multiple keys and each key has again key-value pairs in values

[image]

and I need to change this to this in PostgreSQL

[image]

I tried with `json_array_elements` but in the result, I'm still getting a JSON column for each key in a row, this gives duplicate rows wrt the number of keys I have in a JSON record.

```
SELECT *
  FROM public.ga4 as a
 CROSS JOIN json_array_elements(event_params::json) AS event_params
 LIMIT 100
```

But I want only 1 row and key-value pairs in columns

[image]

Comment: Please please share it as text not picture. Pictures do not help on coding much.

Comment: Can you share your data as code, It can be helpful to help you

Comment: So do you think to share as text at all?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

OK, you are not going to share your data as text and we have to live with that. This should work for your case:

```
with data as (select event_date, event_timestamp, event_name, key, value
              from sampleData,
                   lateral jsonb_to_recordset(event_params) as x(key text, value jsonb))
select event_date,
       event_timestamp,
       event_name,
       max(case when key = 'session_engaged' then value ->> 'string_value' end)         session_engaged,
       max(case when key = 'source' then value ->> 'string_value' end)                  source,
       max(case when key = 'engaged_session_event' then value ->> 'int_value' end::int) engaged_session_event
from data
group by event_date, event_timestamp, event_name;
```

Here is [DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/I7CXFjzp)

EDIT: If your version allows it (v12 or later), there is a much easier version:

```
SELECT event_date, event_timestamp, event_name
     ,jsonb_path_query_first(event_params, '$[*] ? (@.key == "session_engaged")') #>> '{value,string_value}' as session_engaged
     ,jsonb_path_query_first(event_params, '$[*] ? (@.key == "source")') #>> '{value,string_value}' as source
     ,(jsonb_path_query_first(event_params, '$[*] ? (@.key == "engaged_session_event")') #>> '{value,int_value}')::int as engaged_session_event
from sampleData;
```

Here is [DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/h1ZwV7sV)